# Duplicate form names in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form `editQuoteCardForm` within an `ng-repeat` that is repeated multiple times. The form is tied to the `editQuoteCard` model. When a user clicks the edit button, the form is prepopulated with the correct data for the current model.

The problem I'm having is that I can't validate the form by calling `editQuoteCardForm.$valid` because there are multiple instances of `editQuoteCardForm` in the DOM. In fact, if I call `$scope.editQuoteCardForm` within a debugger session, it returns `undefined`.

My question is, how can I properly handle the form name within an `ng-repeat` in such a way that I can validate the form?

Here is the code for my form:

```
<div ng-repeat="c in quoteCards" style="display:none;" id="{{'edit_quote_card_' + c.id + '_form_container'}}">
    <div class="row" id="{{'edit_quote_card_' + c.id + '_form'}}">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row-scrollable" ng-show="view === 'quote-card'">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="editQuoteCardForm" ng-submit="update({card: editQuoteCard, type: 'quote_card'})" novalidate>
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" ng-model="editQuoteCard.token">
                        <input name="id" type="hidden" ng-model="editQuoteCard.id">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <br style="clear:both;" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" ng-model="editQuoteCard.title" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Attribution</label>
                            <br style="clear:both;" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="attribution" ng-model="editQuoteCard.attribution">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Quote</label>
                            <br style="clear:both;" />
                            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" name="quote" ng-model="editQuoteCard.quote" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Media</label>
                            <br style="clear:both;" />
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="photo" ng-model="editQuoteCard.image">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="video" ng-model="editQuoteCard.video">
                            <div class="profile-builder attachment">
                                <div ng-show="editQuoteCard.video" class="content video-content result iframe">
                                    <div class="caption delete-btn" ng-click="editQuoteCard.video = undefined;">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <iframe ng-if="editQuoteCard.video.media_type === 'Youtube'" ng-src="{{editQuoteCard.video.media_url + '?showinfo=0&autohide=1' | trustAsResourceUrl}}" frameborder="0" id="ytplayer" type="text/html"></iframe>
                                    <iframe ng-if="editQuoteCard.video.media_type === 'Vimeo'" ng-src="{{editQuoteCard.video.media_url + '?badge=0&byline=0&title=0' | trustAsResourceUrl}}" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-show="editQuoteCard.image" class="content result">
                                    <div class="delete-btn" ng-click="editQuoteCard.image = undefined;">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="image-container" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + editQuoteCard.image.image_url + ')'}"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br style="clear:both;" />

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update Card" ng-disabled="editQuoteCardForm.$invalid">
                            <div class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" ng-click="openMediaBrowser({type: c.class, id: c.id, index: $index});" ng-show="!editQuoteCard.image && !editQuoteCard.video">Add Media</div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please show your `ng-repeat` code, which is responsible for creating multiple `forms`?

Comment: Just updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create name for each form dynamically.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="editQuoteCardForm{{$index}}" ng-submit="update({card: editQuoteCard, type: 'quote_card'})" novalidate>
</form>
```

So, your forms will be named,

`editQuoteCardForm0`, `editQuoteCardForm1`, `editQuoteCardForm2` etc.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH, any further help?

Comment: Thanks!I marked this as correct, although I've since gone back and adjusted my approach. I refactored the forms as directives to ensure each one has its own scope, thus negating the need to have dynamic form names in the first place.